# How to process data from database with node js?

Tags: mysql, json, node.js

How can I process data from database? I figured out how to get data from mysql database, packed in json file just like in code below:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    console.log('Receving request...');
    var queryData = 'something';
    var callback = function(err, result) {
        res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + queryData + '.json');
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type' : 'x-application/json'
        });
        console.log('json:', result);
        res.end(result);    
    };

connectToDb(callback, queryData);}  
).listen(9999);

function connecToDb(callback, queryData){
var mysql = require('mysql');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host : 'localhost',
        user : 'xxxx',
        password : 'xxxx',
        database : 'xxxx',
        port: 3306
    });

    connection.connect();
    var json = '';
    var data = queryData + '%';
    var query = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE POSTCODE LIKE "' + data + '"';
    connection.query(query, function(err, results, fields) {
        if (err)
            return callback(err, null);

        console.log('The query-result is: ', results);

        // wrap result-set as json
        json = JSON.stringify(results);

        /***************
        * Correction 2: Nest the callback correctly!
        ***************/
        connection.end();
        console.log('JSON-result:', json);
        callback(null, json);
    });
}
```

But I think that's not what I need. How can I use the content of json in global variable, without downloading it this way?

EDIT: One more thing, I need to populate array with data from json so I can process it with another function, that's a final idea.

Comment: "use the content of json" - use it how/where? "downloading it this way" - what way?

Comment: I need data from json (its the data from mysql database) to process it. With "content of json" I mean data from json file. I need this data as an array.  The code I wrote returns json file as a download file in browser.

Comment: You're *converting* it to JSON by doing `json = JSON.stringify(results);`. `results` is an array by default.

Comment: Ok, thank you. That gives me an idea.

Comment: Also the way you're whole http request handler ("`callback`") is written, it's actually *meant* to deliver JSON as a download. So even if you pass it an array it will still trigger download as JSON, unless you change it. Look into how to work with the [http response](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) if you haven't.